# Undeclared identifier, suggested insertion of underscore. Works, but why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, identifier

I'm new to iOS development, currently following along with Lynda's tutorial by Simon Allardice on iOS SDK Essential Training, the chapter on "Creating quick connections."

I'm getting this error message on build:

> "Use of undeclared identifier 'myTextfield'; Did you mean '_myTextfield'?"

The error message implicates this line of code:

```
- (IBAction)changeLabel:(id)sender
{
    NSString *message = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"Hello %@",   myTextfield.text];
}
```

The variable "myTextfield" (spelt correctly, and sans underscore) is clearly declared in the associated header file:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *myTextfield;
```

I'm confounded by the suggestion that I place an underscore in front of the var name. Nevertheless, if I follow this recommendation, the code compiles.

I'm using Xcode 4.6.3 with Lion on a MacBook Pro.

Can someone please suggest a solution to this mystery?

Comment: You should be using `self.myTextfield.text`, not `myTextfield.text`.

Answer (score 3):

A property is not the same thing os a instance variable, you should read a little bit of them, there's plenty of sources in the internet.

Summarizing, a property is the combination of the instance variable (by default, automaticated declaraded with a underscore), and it's get and set methods.

To access the property inside your class, you should call for `self.propertyName`, in your case it would be `self.myTextfield`. This will access the gererated get method of the property. You can always, of course if you are inside the class, skip the get method and access the variable directly. In this case, it would be `_myTextfield`.

If you are not confortable with this automaticated instance variable generated, you can always declare your own and bind it with the property with the `@synthesize` command. Like this:

```
@synthesize myTextfieldProperty = myTextfieldVariable;
```

Here's more information about the `synthesize`. As I said before, this command binds one iVar to a property. So, when you execute the line above, inside your class, you can either reference to the iVar directly, calling `myTextfieldVariable`, or by the property, `self.myTextfieldProperty` (there are a few differences actually between them, but I'm not entering in details).

If you don't write the `synthesize`, what xcode does for you, automatically, is this:

```
@synthesize myTextfield = _myTextfield;
```

So, in your case, as you does not synthesize your property, xcode automatically created the iVar with the underscore in the beginning. It's just a pattern that xcode follows.

The line `@synthesize myTextfield;`, without binding an iVar directly, is simple the same as

```
@synthesize myTextfield = myTextfield;
```

i.e.  you are creating an iVar with the same name of your property. And why these two lines are actyally the same thing?  I don't know, again, it's just a pattern that xcode follows.

Hope that was clear enough, english is not my mother language. Sorry for any mistakes.

Comment: I'm accessing it from outside my class, so self wouldn't apply. However, when I synthesize the property manually, like this: "@synthesize myTextfield;", I can access the property directly using "myTextfield.text". I don't understand, if Xcode 4.6.3 is supposed to be doing the synthesizing, why I need to do it manually. Works, but why?

Comment: Are you sure your property `myTextfield` it's not in the same class of the method `changeLabel:` ?? Anyways, I edited my answer. Please ask if anything was not clear.

Answer (score 1):

Properties are setter and getter methods that are backed by an ivar. When creating a property that is *implicitly synthesized*, the corresponding ivar is created with a leading underscore. This is to remind you that you are directly accessing an ivar directly rather than through a property.

This is because properties take care of memory management for you while direct ivar access does not in non-ARC code. Also, properties handle posting key value observing notifications for you, if you change the value directly, you will need to handle KVO notifications yourself.  Additionally, properties may have the setter or getter overridden to create side effects (e.g. when setting a string on a view, mark the view as needing to be drawn again.). These side effects won't be triggered by direct access.

In you init and dealloc methods you *should* access the ivar directly. In *general*, all other access should be through the setter and getter methods, e.g. `[self setMyTextfield:]` or `self.myTextfield`

One behavior that I find odd is if you *explicitly synthesize* your property by adding `@synthesize myTextfield;` into your implementation file, the ivar that is created does **not** have the leading underscore.

For more information on properties, ivars and setter methods, please read [Apple's Objective-C documentation on the matter](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html)

Comment: @Lucas: Please see above comment. Sounds like Berg and I are similarly confused by the behavior of the auto-synthesize...